# Losing files upon export

Tags: svn, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok developers needing some help here. I am working on a MVC 3 project with another person. My code runs great and builds, but even though he updates his code, his won't build and run. I tried to export it but over 1.2 of the files are being exported.

I'll show screenshots of what's in the bin folder I have and what gets exported.

First the bin folder I have in the project. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve it?[image]

Now the exported bin

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve it?!

Comment: Could it be as simple as just not having added and committed some of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added all the missing files that you expect to be in subversion? You have to do an 'svn add' followed by a commit for them to show up.

Comment: Thank you! That appears to have fixed the issue